# Synchronise Files programmatically/automatically

Tags: file-uploads, extension, sync

I'm using phantomjs via an extension to save a screenshot into an EE file directory, but before it's accessible in the admin area, I need to synchronise files.

I can't see anything in the docs for how to go about this, does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at line 1187 in `system/expressionengine/controllers/cp/content_files.php`. The function `do_sync_files()` is called by the synchronize page. This would be in the EE 2.8.1 core files.

You could probably write a script that calls that function or else re write the logic for your own use (I think it checks a bunch of environment variables that would not let it work from the command line).

Comment: Hmm I attempted the following in an extension:
 
`$cp_path = APPPATH.'controllers/cp/';
include_once($cp_path.'content_files.php');
$this->EE->load->add_package_path($cp_path);
$cp_files = new Content_files();`
 
which resulted in:

`Message: Undefined property: Content_files::$core
Filename: core/EE_Controller.php
Line Number: 33`

Not sure if I'm missing something there, but I fear I may have to rewrite it somewhat. I've got things of higher priority than this at the moment, so I'll hold off trying that for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever get the code for auto sync working? I am in need of the same functionality and would rather not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I'm afraid not, no. As it happened I didn't need the client to actually access the image itself as it was part of a larger project, so I was able to just access the URL.